# Can I get data from SQLite in data source in IntelliJ-idea?

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

I'm a new beginner of java programing language, I SQLite database in the data source in IntelliJ-idea.
I want go connect Sqlite in java but fail to connect.
How to solve this problem?

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owZ6P.png)

[Data source & Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZOfT.png)

[Data source & Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiMqz.png)

```
public class SqliteDB {

Connection c = null;

SqliteDB(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
       c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/mac/Documents/Development/Test");
        System.out.println("Connection to DB OK !!");
        c.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
       SqliteDB db = new SqliteDB();
    }
}
```

I got an error...

> Error:org.sqlite.JDBC

Comment: Did you add the sqlite driver in intellij ? The class is missing

Comment: c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/mac/Documents/Development/Test");

does this a correct connection string

Comment: @sharon182 yes i did

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana yes it is

Comment: First you should change the catch from Exception to the correct exceptions (ClassNotFoundException and SQLException).
Then you should output the error with something more info. For now you could do something like "e.printStackTrace()" (just for now, using printStackTrace is not the correct way or error handling.)